# Aggregate function in r is not working on my dataset

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

Sample Dataset

```
Date   Playerid    Revenue Promo   DayofWeek
01/01/2017  146123  0   B   Sunday
01/01/2017  219378  0   B   Sunday
01/01/2017  198614  0   B   Sunday
02/01/2017  292640  30  A   Monday
02/01/2017  139562  10  A   Monday
02/01/2017  124967  20  A   Monday
02/01/2017  107954  20  A   Monday
03/01/2017  28391   10  B   Tuesday
03/01/2017  184388  21  B   Tuesday
03/01/2017  264222  20  B   Tuesday
03/01/2017  184857  0   B   Tuesday
04/01/2017  79788   40  A   Wednesday
```

I wanted to Aggregate the table by DayofWeek, and sum up the revenue for each day of the week, count the number of players using the playerid such that my final output looks like this:

```
 
Players Revenue Promo   DayofWeek
    3      0      B       Sunday
    4     80      A       Monday
    4     51      B       Tuesday
    1     40      A       Wednesday
```

I have been trying to aggregate the dataset attached above but all attempts were unsuccessful. Can you help, please?

Here is my code below.

```
aggdata <-aggregate(MyData, by=list(DayofWeek,Revenue, Promo, Playerid), 
                    FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I got the following errors

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)
ans <- df %>%
  group_by(DayofWeek) %>%
  summarise(Promo=unique(Promo), Revenue=sum(Revenue), Playerid=n())
```

Output

```
  DayofWeek Promo Revenue Playerid
      <chr> <chr>   <int>    <int>
1    Monday     A      80        4
2    Sunday     B       0        3
3   Tuesday     B      51        4
4 Wednesday     A      40        1
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", 
"02/01/2017", "02/01/2017", "02/01/2017", "02/01/2017", "03/01/2017", 
"03/01/2017", "03/01/2017", "03/01/2017", "04/01/2017"), Playerid = c(146123L, 
219378L, 198614L, 292640L, 139562L, 124967L, 107954L, 28391L, 
184388L, 264222L, 184857L, 79788L), Revenue = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 30L, 
10L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 21L, 20L, 0L, 40L), Promo = c("B", "B", "B", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A"), DayofWeek = c("Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Playerid", "Revenue", "Promo", "DayofWeek"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I tried your solution and it works on the small sample of data provided. But when I loaded the dataset with similar columns as the one I provided earlier, this time containing 30,000 rows, the solution did not work. I attempted doing it this way:   MyData <- read.csv("CustomerData.csv", stringsAsFactor = FALSE).                library(dplyr)
ans <- MyData %>%
  group_by(DayofWeek) %>%
  summarise(Promo=unique(Promo), Revenue=sum(Revenue), Playerid=n())
View(ans)                                                                                           I

Comment: I supposed my problem is with the way I loaded the data

Comment: The errors I got is Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Promo` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3. For more information  MyData has the following struture, str(MylData)
'data.frame': 303345 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Date     : chr  "01/01/2017" "01/01/2017" "01/01/2017" "01/01/2017" ...
 $ Playerid : int  146123 219378 28391 184388 264222 ...
 $ Revenue  : int  0 0 0 30 0 0 20 0 21 20 ...
 $ Promo    : chr  "B" "B" "B" "B" ...
 $ DayofWeek: chr  "Sunday" "Sunday" .

Comment: I also attempted this one  df <- structure(list(MyData), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")) , but it gave the follwoing  df <- structure(list(MyData), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 303345

Comment: Your error occurs because you have multiple Promo values per DayofWeek. Try grouping by `group_by(DayofWeek, Promo)` instead, and summarise `summarise(Revenue=sum(Revenue), Playerid=n())`

Comment: One last thing. What type of regression model will best fit this type of outcome, to predict Revenue, where "promo" is categorical, DayofWeek and PlayerID are the numbers of players? Would you suggest linear or mixed mode regression? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think since you're mixing categorical with numeric classes, mixed mode?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're aggregating by everything except `Date`, so the `sum` function is trying to add up those date strings.  Try summing revenues like this:

```
aggdata <-aggregate(MyData, by=list(DayofWeek, Date, Promo, Playerid), 
                FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Or, from what you're saying, you want to forget about dates:

```
aggdata <-aggregate(. ~ Dayofweek + Promo + Playerid, data = MyData[,-2:5], sum)
```

Comment: After trying your suggestions I got the following errors                                  
> aggdata <-aggregate(. ~ Dayofweek + Promo + Playerid, data = MyData[,-2:4], sum)
Error in .subset(x, j) : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Comment: I will like to aggregate by all columns except the date

Comment: It was hard to guess on exact syntax without sample data.  Please edit your question to include the output of `dput(MyData)`.  Also, I changed my second formula slightly after initially displaying it:  are you using the edited code?

Comment: Whoops:  I realise now you want to use `MyData[,-2:5]`, not `MyData[,-2:4]`.  Fixed it.

Comment: The sample data is attached as a link to an image file, the file name is "Customer Dataset" at the topmost of my question page here. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I am still getting the same error after I made those changes. There must be a way to resolve this problem.  > aggdata <-aggregate(. ~ Dayofweek + Promo + Playerid, data = MyData[,-2:5], sum)
Error in .subset(x, j) : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts. I don't understand this error, can someone please interpret this error

Comment: Apologies for not being clear at the beginning, I have now updated my question to reflect my end goal. Can anyone help, please?